# MS Word: Create cross-reference linking to the top end of a figure, instead of figure labeling text below the image

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, text-editing, cross-reference

I've a problem with *Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2016*:
After I have created a caption text below a figure, and then inside my text set a link to this image, the link will lead me to the labeling below the image. But how can I make links to the top of images? And will the field numbering of images update correctly with the alternative solution?

Comment: You might want to consider placing the figure captions at the top of the image. If you include a table of figures and use PDFs, the reader will open the page with the figure caption at the top of the page and the figure will not be visible without scrolling up.

Comment: Unfortunately the caption must be under images, according to German standards, when writing a final thesis.

Comment: Ah, that's unfortunate. Best of luck on your defense!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've changed my approach from the original answer.  I'm also assuming that your style guide requires the visible caption below the image.  Here's a way you can do this.  You will need to create a new paragraph style and add a SEQ field.  The new style (let's call it "Visible Caption") should 
use the caption style you want to appear to readers of the document.

Next, modify the "Caption" style as follows: use a very small font (e.g. 2 pt), no preceding or following line spacing, and font color white.

Position the cursor above your image and "Insert caption" as you normally would.  Then, move your cursor below the image where you want your visible caption to appear.  Using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F9</kbd>, enter a SEQ field as shown { SEQ VCaption \* ARABIC }

Apply your Visible Caption paragraph style to that line.

Move your cursor to where the table of figures will be located.

Using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F9</kbd>, enter a TOC field as shown { TOC \c "Caption" \h }

You will now have a table of figures that points to the SEQ field located above your image, rather than the visible caption located below your image.  In order to insert cross-references to your hidden caption, you will need to insert cross-references to the figure as you normally would.  In order to see your invisible captions, go to your caption style and change font color to automatic.  Once you're finished and prepared to print, change your Caption font color back to white.  Good luck and comment back if you have questions.

Comment: Thanks's a lot. Meanwhile I had a similar idea: First I created a 1x1 table for each image. Then I started using the normal/preformatted image chaptions below the image (SEQ), just to have a visible caption. Then I added a new caption above the same image, and gave it an extra category name (namely the official abbreviation of the German word for FIGURE). This extra category I use unly for those to-be-invisible captions above the images. Then I made the cross-reference to the unvisible caption over the image. And in the text appears the abbreviation, instead of the pre-formatted whole word.

Comment: I was not testing yet, how to make that extra caption invisible. I was thinking to whiten them all manually. If it will not work, then I would try your proposed method - which sounds a bit complicated to me.

Comment: In my case it's the shortcut Ctrl+Fn+F9(F3). When I saw all those XML codes in my Word document, I was scared to mess up the whole document. So I prefer my approach, which i described in my first comment above. Cheers

Comment: Well, you won't be able to generate a TOC with links using your approach and your figure numbers won't automatically update.  There is no XML, it is a Word field.  Read about field codes here: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/list-of-field-codes-in-word-1ad6d91a-55a7-4a8d-b535-cf7888659a51

Comment: Also, if you're not using styles, you're really making it hard.  By adjusting the font color in the style, you can change it quickly for the entire document.

Answer (score 1):

When I create links in my word documents, I use the Insert > Bookmark feature, in your case I would ensure that the picture is selected then insert bookmark, name this bookmark appropriately ie) image1.

Whenever you would like to return back to this image select the link text and right click > chose hyperlink and select "Place in this document", your bookmarked image should appear in the list. Select this and click okay. When you use this hyperlink in your document it should bring that image up as the top of the page.

Comment: If he uses plain-text figure numbers in the hyperlink text they won't update if he inserts a new image in the middle of the doc. I used to put captions on the bottom before we started using Acrobat ('97). The we found that when anyone opened a figure cross-reference or opened a figure from the List of Figures, the reader always opened the page with the caption at the very top of the page, which forced user to scroll up to see the image.

Comment: I don't think this will work to create a TOC (in this case, a Table of Figures).  A TOC field will only work with styles and a SEQ field, not bookmarks (which don't use a SEQ or common style).

Comment: I think that Bookmarks don't use the right function.
  For automatically updating numbering of tables, figures, and formulas, this SEQ function seems to be the right one. Here is a link to a list of all XML codes, and SEQ is in this list: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/List-of-field-codes-in-Word-1ad6d91a-55a7-4a8d-b535-cf7888659a51